# how to get data from one table and using those values in the same query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. And i want to get data from second table corresponding to value in one row from the first table.

I got two tables   promos  & stores

So what I'm trying to do is first  pull ONE random row from PROMOS first and based on that row also get corresponding data from STORES.

the "category" column  in PROMOS table = STORES (the name of second table)

promos.category = stores

---

promos has the following columns : id,image,category,storeid

stores is the second table that has columns: sid, storename, storeimage

Row in PROMOS table :  1, promopic.png, stores, 2

Row in STORES table :  2, shoppers, shoppers.png,

--

---

UPDATE:
what I'm trying to do is the "stores" name is a row in promos. so the name of the second table i select data from is unknown until we get it from promos table first..

I've tried something like this

`SELECT * FROM promos, promos.category WHERE promos.category.sid ='promos.storeid'`

Comment: are you prevented from doing this in 2 secuential steps with php? "sql only" sounds like a bitter complication considering you added php to your tag list...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ;)

```
set @table_name = (SELECT category FROM promos where id=1); --change the 1 to whatever
set @sql =  CONCAT("select * from ",@table_name);
PREPARE query FROM @sql;
EXECUTE query;
```

The above assumes that you want to select everything from the table name we got from promos.category

Comment: what I'm trying to do is the "stores" name is a row in promos. so the name of the second table i select data from is unknown until we get it from promos table first..

Comment: Don't insert that in php, I thought you are writing a sql script. For your case, understand what the snippet does, and do it in php. As a tip, you will have two queries. One query will get the value of the table name, the second query will use that value (simple string concatenation)

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * FROM promos p LEFT JOIN stores s 
ON s.sid =  p.category
WHERE p.category = {somevalue}
```

Here 
`s.id` stands for `{column name}` of **STORE** which is connecting to **PROMOS** table.